# Deauthorize App from Twitter iOS5 [Accounts Api]

Tags: twitter, ios5

Is it possible to use the new iOS Twitter API to remove an app's integrated twitter authorization.

I am searching for a way to do this from the app itself. You can imagine the user switching a UISwitch to authorize and de-authorize.

What I've found so far is that I can link to the twitter settings app and probably let the user do his deauth there. (Haven't thought it through yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to authorize or deauthorize an application through the Twitter API.  This is a deliberate security decision by the API team.